# What is the difference between std::set and std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, set, binary-search-tree

I'm relatively new to c++ programming and was wondering if someone could help clarify a few questions for me.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

I've been reading on how to implement STL binary search trees and I keep noticing that std::set and std::map are constantly mentioned as the methods for accomplishing such a task. What exactly is the difference between the two however? To me both seem almost identical and I'm not sure if there's something I'm not noticing that makes one better than the other for specific tasks. Is there any advantage of using std::set over std::map for implementing a STL binary search tree that takes values from an array or vector (such as speed for example)?

If someone could help me understand this concept I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: `set` stores elements, unique elements, `map` stores a `pair` composed of a `key` + `value`.

Comment: I don't see how you could use them to implement binary search trees. The interfaces and complexities they specify are a stronger abstraction than binary search trees and they can be implemented in terms of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both `std::set` and `std::map` are `associative containers`. The difference is that `std::sets` contain only the key,
 while in `std::map` there is an associated value , that is if `A -> B` , then map[A]=B , this works like `hashing` but not `O(1)` , instead `O(log N)`.

You can further look [unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/) which provides the operation in `O(1)` time.

`std::set` keeps data in sorted format .
Implementation of both is done by balanced trees (like AVL or Red-Black trees ) giving `O(logN)` time complexity.

But important point to note is that both can store **unique values** . To overcome that you must see also [multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/multimap/) and [multiset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/) .

Hope this helps !

**update:** In the case of Red-Black tree re-balancing rotation is an `O(1)` operation while with AVL this is a `O(log n)` operation, making the Red-Black tree more efficient in this aspect of the re-balancing stage and one of the possible reasons that it is more commonly used.

Comment: So say for instance I've got an array or vector that has nothing but integer values. If I want to store all of those values in a binary search tree, a set would manage to do everything that I want and there wouldn't be need for a map? Just trying to make sure I understand correctly

Comment: exactly ! But you should know that these inbuilt features are somewhat slow than if you make them from scratch in `C` .

Comment: @Aseem Goyal You mean the typical std library implementations of std::map, std::unordered_map and so on are slower than if you were to write your own container using raw C?