# How to initialize a map from a set

Tags: c++, stdmap, stdset

I want to set the keys of a `std::map` using the elements of a `std::set` (or a `std::vector`).

Something like the following...

```
std::set<int> keys = { 3,4,6 };
std::map<int,string> results(keys); // syntax error
```

Can this be done without explicitly iterating over the set?

Comment: 1) Is there any particular reason you want to? 2) What do you want the value strings to be?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this were possible, since accessing the uninitialized values that would result from that statement should not be permissible behavior.

Comment: @Beta: 1) I want to create an API that allows the keys to be specified concisely (without regard to values).  2) I want the value to be default initialized.

Comment: But why do you want to not explicitly iterate over the set? Unless you have a specific reason, I think this is more a question about coding style.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, it is essentially for style.  I'm just wondering if there is a very concise way to make the assignment.  It seems like it might be a natural thing to do based on [the similarities between the two containers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21804128).

Comment: I think it can be done, by some very adroit STL-jutsu, but it will much less concise -- and readable, and maintainable -- than straightforward iteration over the set.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish But that's exactly what map::operator[] allows -- default-initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. A `map` is not a `set`. They're fundamentally different containers, even if the underlying structure is similar.

---

That said, anything's possible. The range constructor of `std::map` is linear time if the elements of the range are already sorted, which `set` guarantees for us. So all you need to do is apply a transformer to every element to produce a new range. The simplest would be to just use something like [`boost::make_transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) (or roll your own):

```
template <class K, class F
    class V = decltype(std::declval<F&>()(std::declval<K const&>()))::second_type>
std::map<K, V> as_map(std::set<K> const& s, F&& f) {
    return std::map<K,V>(
        boost::make_transform_iterator(s.begin(), f),
        boost::make_transform_iterator(s.end(), f));
}

std::map<int,string> results =
    as_map(keys, [](int i){
        return std::make_pair(i, std::string{});
    });
```

which if you always will want default initialization, can just reduce to:

```
template <class V, class K>
std::map<K, V> as_map_default(std::set<K> const& s) {
    auto f = [](K const& k) { return std::make_pair(k, V{}); }
    return std::map<K,V>(
        boost::make_transform_iterator(s.begin(), f),
        boost::make_transform_iterator(s.end(), f)); 
}

std::map<int,string> results = as_map_default<string>(keys);
```

Comment: Every time someone says "the simplest solution would be X", and X involves the line that defines `class V`, someone swears to never learn C++. :-) Note: I like the answer, but man, so many angle brackets.

Comment: The answer starts by saying "you can't", then proceeds to demonstrate how to do it. The iteration is hidden inside the map constructor, which is basically what I was hoping to see.  So this is the correct answer, except for the first two words. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Can this be done without explicitly iterating over the set?

No. There is no way to know the keys in the set without iterating over it. You may write functions to make it *appear* as if there is an implicit transformation, but those functions must ultimately iterate the source collection.

A simple way is as follows:

```
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <string>

auto build_map(const std::set<int>& source) -> std::map<int,std::string>
{
  std::map<int,std::string> results;
  for (auto const& i : source) {
    results[i];
  }
  return results;
}

int main()
{
  std::set<int> keys = { 3,4,6 };
  auto results = build_map(keys);
}
```

Of course we may templatise if that improves readability:

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template<class MappedType, class SourceContainer>
auto build_map(SourceContainer&& source)
{
  using source_type = std::decay_t<SourceContainer>;
  using key_type = typename source_type::value_type;

  std::map<key_type , MappedType> results;
  for (auto const& i : source) {
    results[i];
  }
  return results;
}

int main()
{
  std::set<int> keys = { 3,4,6 };
  auto results = build_map<std::string>(keys);

  // also
  results = build_map<std::string>(std::vector<int>{3, 4, 6});
  results = build_map<std::string>(std::unordered_set<int>{3, 4, 6});
}
```

Comment: A nice example of how to do the iteration-based initialization very simply.